# I need to create a database structure that will do the following

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i want to be able to upload multiple images (i got this working) its array

only problem is i need each image to have its own content but i want to use one form as this relates to a specific article.As you see this picture

This welcome article for example has a heading, an image and text to explain for each image .

this is my current db structure but as you can see there is no way content will be separate for each image

article id is the foreign key

How could i achieve this in a database structure?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. How is the image content not separate for each image?

Comment: @Alternatex  i need to pull each image and each image content seperately from the database. so i have image 1 then i need content for that image 1 and i have image 2 and i need content for that image 2. Should i just create different text area fields or in the databse have fields like content_1 and content_2 ect..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You talking about uploading images to your server right ? if so:
You got few options to do it:

1. Create a 'unique' id and put them inside the image element and the content element.
   Then you will get two arrays and you combine them by the unique.
2. Almost the same, just simply to store the content and the images inside arrays. and just loop through them and 'combine' them by the array's id. because you inserting the same amount so it should be the same. But answer 1 is safer here.

Comment: thanks man but could you provide me an example for option1?

Comment: Are you gonna use javascript here ?

Comment: no im just going to use php

Comment: do you mean something like this 
$content=$_POST['content'];
for($i=0; $i<count($content);$i++){
 $contents=$content[$i];
 echo $contents ."<br/>";
}